# Gradle include a multi-module submodule in another project outside the root module

Tags: gradle, dependencies, multi-module

This is my situation. I have a Multi Module Project (MP) and an external project (EP)

```
MP
|_ S1
|_ S2

EP
|_ I want to include S1
```

I would like to include the S1 submodule of MP as a project dependency of the external project EP. Is it possibile?

I'm able to include it as a jar dependency (with version) publishing ER into maven local. But I need to include it as a project dependecy without version, in order to be recognized by my IDE (avoiding each time to build and publish EP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/userguide/composite_builds.html#header), as this is the Gradle solution for such problems.

You will most likely have to include the full MP project in the EP project, since S1 may not be fully defined outside of the MP context.

Comment: thanks. I resolved with includeBuild and dependencySubstitution. It works.